# TSQL Replace Doubled Characters

Tags: t-sql, replace, sql-server-2014

Let's say I have data:

```
heloo
cuube
triniity
```

How to write script that will replace those "doubled" characters with only one? So the result from the above data set would be:

```
helo
cube
trinity
```

Usually I post some script where I tried to achieve this, but this time I can't think of any.

Comment: How should this imaginary script know whether the doubled characters are actually meant to be deleted, or if they're legitimately part of a correctly spelled word? What is the context in which it's needed? Because it sounds like, if possible, you'd be better to use a preexisting spell-checking library, which would probably be best placed in a different application layer/language.

Comment: Everything that's doubled should be replaced, no exception.

Comment: then it's very easy to conceptualise. for each character in string, if this character is the first one, or does not equal the previous character, then add this character to the end of a separate 'corrected string' variable. this will handle triplets and higher, too, so if you want something else, better specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script does not depend on having access to master functions, and just relies on t-sql string functions.

```
declare @word varchar(100) = 'aaaacuuuuuubeeeee', @result varchar(100) = ''
declare @letter char, @idx int = 0, @lastletter char = ''

while(@idx <= len(@word))
begin
    select @letter = substring(@word,@idx,1)
    if (@letter != @lastletter)
    begin
        select @result = concat(@result,@letter)
    end
    select @lastletter = @letter,@idx = @idx + 1
end

select @result
```

Comment: Thank you. As this one was more educational to me, I prefer this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE remove_duplicate_characters(@string VARCHAR(100)) 
AS
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(100) 

SET @result=''
SELECT @result=@result+MIN(SUBSTRING(@string ,number,1)) FROM
(     
    SELECT number FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='p' AND number BETWEEN 1 AND len(@string )) AS t GROUP BY SUBSTRING(@string,number,1) ORDER BY MIN(number)
)

SELECT @result  
GO
```

You then call it like this:

```
EXEC remove_duplicate_characters 'heloo'
```

[Source](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10819/remove-duplicate-characters-from-a-string.aspx)